# Mongodb doesn't save the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a CRUD with mongodb, and doesn't throw a error, but when I try to insert the data, the data is not inserted. Someone help me please

App.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

// connecting to db
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/crud', { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(db => console.log('DB connected'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

// importing routes
const indexRoutes = require('./routes/index');

// settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  

// middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// routes
app.use('/', indexRoutes);

// starting the server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Server on port ${app.get('port')}`);
});
```

index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Task = require('../models/task');

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const tasks = await Task.find();
  res.render('index', {
    tasks
  });
});

router.post('/add', async (req, res, next) => {
  const task = new Task(req.body);
  console.log(req.body)
  await task.save();
  res.redirect('/');
})

module.exports = router;
```

task.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const TaskSchema = Schema({
    CLiente: String ,
    Correo: String ,
    Direccion: String ,
    Telefono: Number 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('tasks', TaskSchema);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In task.js,  You are doing minor mistake , initialise Schema and then assign it to TaskSchema.

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  const TaskSchema = new Schema({
      CLiente: String ,
      Correo: String ,
      Direccion: String ,
      Telefono: Number 
  });

  module.exports = mongoose.model('tasks', TaskSchema);
```